# Optimization of Index coloring problem with one color adjacent allowed

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, backtracking, recursive-backtracking, graph-coloring

I came across this index coloring problem (not exactly a typical Graph m-coloring problem) which I tried to solve using backtracking but the solution only works properly for lower-valued test cases and fails for larger ones due to exponential time complexity.

**How can I optimize it such that it doesn't run in exponential time. Is there a DP approach to solve this?**

> Problem statement:
>
> You are given 3 variables: n, k, x
>
> n -> Number of indices to be colored
>
> k -> Number of colors available -> 1,2,3,...K
>
> x -> Color ID which can be used to color two adjacent indices.
>
> You have to color **n indices**
> placed on the x-axis with **k colors** such that no two      adjacent
> indices have the same color.
> However, you are also given **x which is
> a colorID**      which is an exception to the above rule such that it
> is allowed to have two adjacent nodes    with color = colorID.
>
> **You have to find out total number of ways all indices can be colored while following the above rules.**

> Example. For, n = 3 k = 2 x = 1 : All possible solutions are: (1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,2,1), (2,1,1), (2,1,2)

Following is my solution.

```
public class ColoringIndices {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 17;
        int k = 4;
        int x = 3;
        placeColors(n, k, x);
    }

    static int count = 0;

    private static void placeColors(int n, int k, int x) {
        int currpos = 0;
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        placeColorsUtil(n, k, x, currpos, arr);
        System.out.println(count % 1000000007);
        count = 0;
    }

    private static void placeColorsUtil(int n, int k, int x, int currpos, int[] arr) {
        if(currpos == n){
            int mod = 1000000007;
            count = count % mod;
            count++;
            return;
        }

        for (int colorId = 1; colorId <= k; colorId++) {
            if (isSafe(colorId, currpos, arr, x)) {
                arr[currpos] = colorId;
                placeColorsUtil(n, k, x, currpos + 1, arr);
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isSafe(int colorId, int currpos, int[] arr, int x) {
        if (currpos < arr.length && currpos > 0) {
            if (colorId != x && arr[currpos - 1] == colorId) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: "allowed to have two..."  Are you allowed 3 adjacent nodes of the special color?

Comment: @MattTimmermans Solution `(1, 1, 1)` would seem to indicate so.

Comment: Ah, right.  Missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the DP is whether the last index colored was `x`. We get two recurrences

```
X(n) = number of valid sequences of length n ending in x
Y(n) = number of valid sequences of length n not ending in x

X(1) = 1
Y(1) = k-1

X(n+1) = X(n) + Y(n)
         |  |   \__/
          \/     continue sequence not ending in x with x
           continue sequence ending in x with another x

Y(n+1) = (k-1) X(n) + (k-2) Y(n)
         |        |   \________/
         |        |    continue sequence not ending in x in k-2 possible ways
          \______/     (excluding the last color (not x in this case) and x)
           continue sequence ending in x in k-1 possible ways (excl. x)
```

which can be evaluated in time `O(n)`. The answer is `X(n) + Y(n)` (or `0` if `n` is zero).

<strike>For posterity, I'll try to get an analytic solution.</strike> Meh, the presence of `k` makes this unfun. In practice you'd just be evaluating the appropriate power of the matrix

```
( 1   1 )
(k-1 k-2)
```

anyway.

Comment: Is this what you mean?private static void placeColors(int n, int k, int x) {
        int[][] dp = new int[2][n];
        dp[0][0] = 1;
        dp[1][0] = k - 1;
        int mod = 1000000007;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            dp[0][i] = (dp[0][i - 1] % mod + dp[1][i - 1] % mod) % mod;
            dp[1][i] = (((k - 1) * dp[0][i - 1]) % mod + ((k - 2) * dp[1][i - 1]) % mod) % mod;
        }
        System.out.println(dp[0][n - 1] + dp[1][n - 1]);
    }

Comment: @JatinShashoo Yes (up to typos), though you don't need to keep the whole array around.

Comment: Agreed. Could have used 2 variables instead and kept updating their values at each iteration. This feels like such an easy problem after looking at your DP explanation. I couldn't think of this earlier in an interview. Backtracking seemed like the only intuitive solution at that time.